# com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am using Android Studio 0.4.2. Opened project from a friend who is using 0.3.2. Tried to compile but got exception.

```
Execution failed for task ':JuiceTV:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    C:\Program Files\Android\android-studio\sdk\build-tools\19.0.0\dx.bat --dex --output D:\Antik TV - Android\JuiceTV\build\libs\JuiceTV-debug.dex D:\Antik TV - Android\JuiceTV\build\classes\debug D:\Antik TV - Android\JuiceTV\build\dependency-cache\debug D:\Antik TV - Android\JuiceTV\build\pre-dexed\debug\classes-ffe9228b675e120536184b1056a59fcfc91e4006.jar D:\Antik TV - Android\JuiceTV\build\pre-dexed\debug\commons-io-2.4-27f1277ba9e42db4b52f3f658da01a26db29b896.jar D:\Antik TV - Android\JuiceTV\build\pre-dexed\debug\joda-time-2.2-4549e2440d188ee3fb4f85702e03eace13e8ad18.jar D:\Antik TV - Android\JuiceTV\build\pre-dexed\debug\mmlib-04a4fd100008bfbc84f0c25fd219e50eb7de9d0b.jar D:\Antik TV - Android\JuiceTV\build\pre-dexed\debug\support-v4-18.0.0-ba816fc3ae00ee0fdb20e5444c1d8bb88647d773.jar
Error Code:
    2
Output:
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/sevensoft/mmlib/AttachedOverlayWindow$1;
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:593)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:551)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:532)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:169)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:187)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:439)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:287)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)
```

Tried this things:

- deleting *.apk files
- searching for dependencies with **gradle -q dependencies** 
  but got nothing

JuiceTV Gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':TVbase')
}
```

BaseTv Gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android-library'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+'
    compile files('libs/joda-time-2.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/mmlib.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-io-2.4.jar')
}
```

Any new tips?

Comment: try this : clean your project from `Build > Clean Project` than use `File > Inavlidate Cache/ Restart` .

Comment: Could you tell me where I could do the same in eclipse?

Comment: In my case `./gradlew clean` works and __NOT__`./gradlew android:clean`

Answer (score 18):

I just had the same issue and I discovered that my application and a library were referring to 2 versions of the same jar.

I did a search and my application.iml file clearly showed the duplicates.

```
<orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="crittercism_v3_0_11_sdkonly" level="project" />
<orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="crittercism_v4_4_0" level="project" />
```

I replaced the older v3 version with the v4 version and it worked after a clean rebuild.

Comment: how did you do this search?

Comment: If that dependencies came from 3rd party libraries, you can declare same, up to date library in your build.gradle, or remove old version from library by exclude statement.

Comment: I solved my problem using the dependency graph in gradle. Using the gradle wrapper I ran ./gradlew dependencies to see the graph and then you search through if.

Remember you might need to run a ./gradlew app:dependencies or ./gradlew lib:dependencies, depending on how your project is structured

Answer (score 7):

This happens when a Module has a dependency on both another module and that same module's jar.

Comment: I had same problem. Initially I had a project as an aar dependency and when I added the same project as a direct module I forgot to remove the aar dependency.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue on android studio 1.0, along with removing the duplicate entry for libraries you should also try deleting the bin folders and do a clean build.

Answer (score 2):

As of Android Gradle 1.0 this can happen a few ways:

1. If you only use Maven repos you can run into this issue if **two different artifacts include the same class file**.
   The [Mockito-all](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-all/1.10.19) library, for instance, includes Hamcrest and you would therefore cause this error if you included both dependencies in a build.
   Note, if you have minification turned on you won't see the error until you start using Hamcrest. The way to resolve this is to use a version of the library that isn't including other package's classes (Mockito-core in this case).
2. If you declare a **local jar/aar** dependency (`compile 'com.some.library:some-artiface-version_number@aar'`) that is **already being included by other maven-based dependencies**.
   In this situation your local declaration doesn't get de-duped with the Maven one because the pom information isn't available. You would typically create a local, file-based maven repo for the aar to get around this.

In either case, a project clean is required to pickup the changes.

Answer (score 1):

Having multiDex disabled and incremental in dexOptions enabled will also cause this issue.

```
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled = false
 }
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    incremental true
}
```