# fresco and appcompat-v7 build error

Tags: android, android-appcompat, fresco

In my gralde file ,I add ONLY  two complies:

> compile ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0')
>   compile('com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.14.1')

When build project, I got this error:

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException:
>   Multiple dex files define
>   Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;

While I exclude support-v4 like below, error exists also.

> ```
>  compile ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0') 
>         {
>              exclude module: 'support-v4' 
>         }
> ```
>
> OR
>
> ```
>  compile('com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.14.1') 
>         { 
>             exclude module: 'support-v4' 
>         }
> ```

Any of them don't work.

I was sad , I didn't find the solve way , wasted a whole day!

Comment: Can you try adding `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:{VERSION}'`

Comment: What's your `minSdkVersion`?

Comment: remove `{
             exclude module: 'support-v4' 
        } `

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21735493/com-android-dex-dexexception-multiple-dex-files-define

Comment: minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

Answer (score 0):

Updating your support library to v24.2.1 should fix this.